# ''Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda'' with dual boot Win 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a Hard disk With 2 partitions and Windows 10 installed in one of them, so i wanted to do a dual boot with Ubuntu15.10 . I tried to do it but something got wrong and windows cant boot.

Ubuntu is not able to finish the installation because of this error (`Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda`). I tried a lot of things and now i have 5 or 6 partitions and i don't even know where is Windows.I tried with boot repair, but i also have another error, i have the link of the info here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15247602/

Thats all, i hope someone can help me without erasing all my data from Windows 10

Comment: I am surprised Ubuntu even installed. It used to be with dynamic partitions (shown as SFS) that Ubuntu would not even see entire drive. Best to undo dynamic partitions. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html

Comment: I cant do nothing in windows, this will solve my problem?   I tried to disable UEFI from the BIOS but i cant find it. And ubuntu is not installed, i only can 'try ubuntu without installing'

Comment: Then best to use ISO and boot it. Not from within Windows. See instructions. Do not use Windows so link is best I can do.

Comment: Thanks oldfred, but i just erased everything And installed Ubuntu so it works now. Sorry for wasting you time :)

Answer (score 0):

You're in deep trouble. Your Windows installation uses the Windows [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) configuration, aka "dynamic disks," indicated in MBR by a type-0x42 partition type. Ubuntu doesn't play nice with this Microsoft-specific partition type. It appears, though, that you've modified the LDM container partitions, which may well have damaged them.

Your best bet is to use *Windows* recovery tools to back up all your important data and then start again from scratch -- that is, re-install both Windows and Ubuntu.

When you move forward, I recommend installing both Windows and Ubuntu in EFI mode; using BIOS mode complicates the boot path, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) Before you do more, here's some extra reading:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog.
- **[The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)** -- This page is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.

Comment: Thank you @Rod Smith,  but i erased all data and installed just ubuntu :) Im going to format the disk and install Win, and i think i have no problem about doing that.